# Why drupal always shows the content of / (root)?

Tags: drupal, ubuntu, vps

After moving a Drupal site from one VPS to another, the site loads the front page without problem, i.e. `http://www.example.com/`

However, no matter which link I click, e.g:

```
 http://www.example.com/user
 http://www.example.com/node/2
```

the content is same as `http://www.example.com/`. The URLs in browser address bar are updated though.

Comment: try disabling clean urls ..

Comment: thanks! it's (temporary) fixed by http://www.example.com/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `.htaccess` file made it to the new site.  It should be in the same directory as index.php. Sometimes programs will ignore it since it starts with a dot, and it fails to get moved.

If it does exist, mod rewrite needs to be enabled if the web server is apache... or if Nginx, the site configuration needs to support rewriting the request string.